# HTTP POST from Android to PHP not working for certain domain

Tags: php, android, post, permissions

I am trying to send data from an Android app to a PHP file on my server (school server) but I'm running into some problems. I have my own hosting space through SimpleHelix, and I was able to send the data just fine, but when I try to use my school's server, the PHP program returns the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: message in /home/alespurg/test_good.php on line 4

Warning: file_put_contents(androidmessages.html) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/alespurg/test_good.php on line 9

Warning: file_get_contents(androidmessages.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/alespurg/test_good.php on line 11
```

All I have changed in my Java file is the URL that I need it to post to. Could there be restrictions on my school's server that prevent the post to go through? I've checked my permissions on the folders and files, they're all 775. Again, I know the program works, I'm just having problems with the server. I did not use the IP address of the domain for either one. I couldn't find it for my school's server.

EDIT:

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$message=$_POST["message"];

// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="androidmessages.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
// load the contents of the file to a variable
$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
// display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

Comment: We need to see the PHP code generating that error and the contents you're POSTing in order to give you realistic help.

Comment: I added the PHP code to the original post. Thanks

Comment: Oh, how I love simple code!  Can you show the POSTed data?  It looks like you're missing the `message` key in the data...

Comment: The message key is what's sent from the Android app. I can't figure out why it's not getting through because it worked fine when I used my personal hosting space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the permissions are **775** that means that if the web server process isn't either **(1)** the user who owns */home/alespurg/* (not likely) or **(2)** a member of the group that owns */home/alespurg/* (also not likely) then it won't be able write to the directory.

Are you sure the web server process is the owner or a member of the ownership group for */home/alespurg/*?

I'll assume your web server is apache, which usually runs as *apache:apache* or *nobody:nobody*. Judging from the directory structure, it's likely that */home/alespurg/* is owned by *alespurg:alespurg* or some derivation.

---

**ADDENDUM**

If you need to do things like this an apache process is not really the appropriate place. You may not know it but you can write php scripts and execute them from the shell environment on your server **where you're logged in as the appropriate user to write to that directory**. Further, you can have CRON run them for you if necessary. The web server process is an unnecessary middleman.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Could you explain further? What steps should I take from here?

Comment: The chmod system works like this: **4-2-1** Where 4 is the read bit, 2 is the write bit, and 1 is the execute bit. You add the three numbers together to determine what permissions an entity has to a particular file or directory. The three numbers in **775** represent the access level for Owner-Group-World, So 7 means 4+2+1 = full read/write/execute access. If apache isn't the actual owner or a member of the same group as the owner it falls into the third (World) category. So 4+1 = 5, meaning apache doesn't have the **2** (write) capability on that directory.

Comment: Apache can't just run around your server with write access to directories or bad things could happen. If the code worked on a different server it means either the apache process had write access to the directories in question as a user/group member -OR- the directories were `chmod`ed to 777. You probably have the ability to chmod the directories in your own */home/alespurg* path if you want to make a directory writable for apache.

Comment: Oh, and it doesn't affect your permissions issue but you can avoid the notice about "undefined index ... blah blah" by (1) ensuring that the `message` key *was actually POSTed* or (2) verifying it exists before you reference it like so: `$msg = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : NULL;`

Comment: I just tried it on a different school server that I have access to. It's working now. Thanks for your help!